# Why is there no warning on NuGet target framework mismatch?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 (`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`). Its associated `packages.config` file looks like this:

```
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I can restore and compile the project without any warnings. But according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema), I would expect a warning saying that there is a mismatch between `net45` (`packages.config`) and `v4.6.2` (`MyProject.csproj`).

I'd like to understand why there is no warning.

Comment: I'd need to check but I think log4net only has a net45 build and no explicit build for later versions. Why would the system warn you when there's no better alternative version to select? Admittedly, I can't find documentation that states it does this, but it would seem to make sense.

Comment: Within [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema), I can find the following sentence: *A mismatch between the project's target and targetFramework attributes will generate warnings, in which case you can reinstall the affected packages.* But you're right, there seems to be some logic that checks whether a warning does make sense